# Sum columns value in a specific order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to know if I can sum the values of a `float(53)` column in ascending order.

For example, if my column contains the values 5, 7 and 2. I'd like it to be computed as 2+5+7.

This order matters in my case as I'm summing millions of floats and it gives a different result at each execution.

Comment: My advice is to store these as numerics rather than floats.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you can get the sum using window functions and filtering:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(col) over (order by col asc) as sum_col,
             row_number() over (order by col desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Or alternatively without a subquery:

```
select top (1) sum(col) over (order by col asc)
from t
order by col desc;
```

Note:  This assumes that `col` has unique values.  If duplicates are possible, just add the primary key as a second column in the `order by`s.

However, if the data can be stored using `numeric`/`decimal`, that might be a more sustainable solution.